# Why is my horizontal navigation off center?

Tags: html, css

This issue is driving me insane.  My navigation links and logo are suppose to be horizontally centered in my header with logo directly in the center of my nav links.  For some reason everything is slightly off center and shifted approx 3/4" to the left.  I'm new at web building and have spent hours researching and experimenting with different code. I cannot figure out what I need to change or add to fix things and get everything perfectly centered. Help is greatly appreciated.

I'm going to include code for the hover effect just in case my issue lies there.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.cc_nav {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  height: 20%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cc_nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  margin: 0 40px;
  font-family: Tenar Sans;
  font-size: .8em;
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

#logo_Claire {
  max-height: 140px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.noHover:hover::before {
  background: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="cc_nav" id="centered_nav">
    <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
    <a href="services.html">SERVICES</a>
    <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
    <a href="index.html" class="noHover"><img src="images/logo_6.png" alt="Claire Crawford" id="logo_Claire" /></a>
    <a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
    <a href="blog.html">BLOG</a>
    <a href="contact.html">GET IN TOUCH</a>
    <div>
</header>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean, everything looks centered to me. Are you looking at it when the first link is at the edge of your screen and there is a space on the left side of the first link?

Comment: No. Everything is shifted about 3/4" to the left ... every link and my logo

Comment: Can you add a screenshot and highlight where this shift is? You do have 40px margin on both side of all of your links, is that the space you are seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's because each item in your navigation has a different width, longer words are wider, so if you have the same amount of items in each side but the ones in the right are longer the others appear to go to the left.

Try adding

```
a {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: `Flex: 1` is shorthand for: `flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 1; flex-basis: auto`. Because of that, setting a `flex-basis` before a legal value of `flex` has no use. Besides this, your answer works perfectly.

Comment: This fixed the centering issue.  Thank you!.  It's cut off one side of my logo and has spread out the links .. but I think I can figure out how to fix all that.  The main issue was getting it centered and your code did that for me. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I was able to fix the logo by eliminating the margin but I can't figure out how to bring my nav links closer together. I don't want them spread out the way that they currently are - across the entire width of the header. Can you give me advice on how to correct this issue?

Comment: you could place them inside a div as a container and limit its width.